# Cache::remember causing exception in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm struggling to cache a query in Laravel 5. I've written the following code, which looks consistent with what's in the documentation:

```
    // Get ID
    $id = Auth::id();

    // Get user
    $user = Cache::remember('user-' . $id, 5, function ($id) { 
        return User::find($id);
    });
```

But it raises the following error:

```
Missing argument 1 for App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::{closure}()
```

Any idea where I've gone awry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead, mechanism for adding methods to closure functions is bit different than you are using.

```php
$user = Cache::remember('user-' . $id, 5, function() use ($id) { 
    return User::find($id); //                       ^^^
});
```